# How do I normalize CSS in Atom?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hardcode a prototype from XD. I just downloaded Atom to get started, however I am struggling with getting my CSS to work, since I don't think it is normalized. I am not sure how to do this. Any help?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/ 
It pretty much does everything for you. There is a CDN ready version as well as an NPM package. I think it takes care of all CSS normalization for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are talking about Adobe XD.
Imo, the best way would be to write a dedicated CSS file, and have it linked into your hardcoded prototype (like this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).